# I received an email alert about a message in my Stack Exchange Inbox, but it was missing

Tags: support, notifications, meta, global-inbox, email-notification

I'm guessing that this message was deleted because the question I commented on was put On Hold, or because the comment was from the requester. Can someone confirm that this is known behavior, explain the criteria for removing messages from my inbox, and explain the rationale?

Further, the message was cut off in the email (particularly frustrating because the boilerplate in that email amounts to 10x the text that was shown, which is presumably short due to the limits on comment length), and I don't know how to review the contents.  Any help on that front would also be appreciated.

Comment: If the comment was deleted, it is gone. Sometimes people post something and change their mind. Sometimes comments get flagged and deleted, sometimes they just get deleted. Not much you can do about it. Diamond moderators can see deleted comments, but I don’t think you should bother them just because you’re curious about a deleted comment.

Comment: That is helpful in the sense that it could explain the outcome (I'm guessing that there is no announcement that a comment I was notified about was deleted?).  I guess in that case the second part of my question would qualify as a feature request.  You are welcome to propose that as an answer.  In the text that I did get, I didn't see any reason to delete the comment, but who knows.

Comment: I agree that comments are short enough to send the whole thing by email. Maybe they want the extra page views, so try to get you to log on to read the comment.

Comment: It's not possible to unsend an email (or app notifications, since the apps have a similar problem). But you can't see deleted comments so the notification is removed from the one place it can be removed from: your SE inbox.

Comment: Is user deletion of their own comment the only way a comment is deleted, or are there other ways?  Does something automatic happen if a question is put "on hold", or is a moderator also able to delete comments (is there oversight of this power?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you receive a comment (anywhere), an answer to your question, or a chat ping, and it is deleted before you see it, the notice is removed from your inbox.  Email, however, can't be retracted once sent, so you'll see it there.

Inbox messages, both in your inbox and via email, are limited to the first few words.  I'm not sure what the limit is, but I think it's under 100 characters.

Yes, it can be tantalizing, especially when it looks like you got an answer but it got nuked before you saw it.  Yes, that probably means it wasn't really an answer, but it still leaves you wondering.  I don't know what SE could do about that, though -- it's just a bit of mystery that we have to put up with sometimes as the price for getting timely email notifications.